# How to remove <h1> tag from jQuery mobile loader?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery 1.4.5 on my page and use the loader ahead of an ajax request:

```
$.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"e", text:"", textonly:false, textVisible: false});
```

After finishing the request, I hide it:

```
$.mobile.loading('hide');
```

That works, but it produces an  tag at the end of the page where the text would be located.

```
<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-e ui-loader-default">
 <span class="ui-icon-loading"></span>
 <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Several SEO tools are now issuing a warning due to this second h1 tag.

How can I remove the  tag from the loader?

Comment: Did u try jQuery's `remove()` method?

Comment: @PirateofMarmara I haven't seen your comment before answering, you've asked when I was afk. You are welcome.

Comment: no, how does that work? you mean .loading.remove() ?

Comment: @Arfeo, No problem. You may answer after he tries and that works.

Comment: @merlin, Check [this](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: @PirateofMarmara thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the needed element with the jQuery `remove` method.

```js
$('.ui-loader').find('h1').remove();
```

Comment: I asked if he tried that method. You'd better wait.

Comment: Hey, that worked. Thank you. Is this the recommended way? Finding something sounds expensive. Unfortunatelly the textvisible=false does not seem to have an affect.

Comment: What does `the textvisible=false does not seem to have an affect` mean? @merlin

Comment: Well in my question the show loading command has an attribute "textvisible". It is set to false. On might think that this will remove the h1 tag itself.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way, according to the docs https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html. As I can see on the sample page, this component doesn't remove `ui-loader` after hide. It uses toggling of the `ui-loading` attribute of `html` tag. Poor tool. @merlin

Comment: OK, thank you. Let's hope they will continue and release 2.0 sometime.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/remove/):

> Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.
>
> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach() instead.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $("h1").remove();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>H1 Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am always a little bit too late to the party, but if You need to customize the JQM loader, please be aware that, near the options described in Your question, You can supply also the `html` parameter.

First of all, You need to set Your custom `html` without the unwanted `h1` tag during JQM initialization:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    /* jQuery Mobile initialization */
    var html = "<div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon-loading'></span></div>";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.defaultHtml = html;
    // ... other settings as You need
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
  });
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

After that, You can show the `loader` as-is without any text message or - when You need anyway to show a loading `message` - You can customize it further, always by using the `html` option:

```
var html = "<div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon-loading'></span><h6>Wait...</h6></div>";
$.mobile.loading("option", "html", html);
$.mobile.loading("show");
```

---

Please note:

The standard `textVisible` option will not work anymore this way, because by default JQM is searching for the `h1` tag which doesn't exist anymore inside the loader markup. This shall be fixed inside JQM source code, with something that allows a more flexible configuration, without hard-coding the `h1` tag:

```
1513                this.element.find( "h1" ).text( message );
```